# Is there a way to compile MS-DOS programs on Windows 7?

Tags: c, windows, compilation, dos

I want to compile C/C++ programs that are supposed to run on MS-DOS, can I do this without actually installing DOS?

If I can not, can I use a virtual machine as a work-around? (I tried this before asking but I can't see if they will work on an actual DOS on a physical machine)

Comment: You say "supposed to run on MS-DOS" but many people call console (command prompt) windows DOS windows. If the programs are truly not DOS then trying to make them DOS will of course be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- there are compiler toolchains like [DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) and [OpenWatcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/) which can build DOS executables on a Windows (or even Linux!) system.

Alternatively, if you already have a DOS toolchain that you want to use, you can certainly run that under an emulator like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/).

Comment: Actually, DJGPP creates 32-bit executables that run under a 32-bit DOS extender under MS-DOS.

Comment: @RossRidge Interesting -- I didn't know that detail! As penance, added another compiler option that _can_ target 16-bit DOS.